# How to prevent insertion of row which differs only in primary key from existing row?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, insert, primary-key, duplication

If my table contains the following

```
+----+-----+------------+-----------+
| id | uid | date       | operation |
+----+-----+------------+-----------+
| 1  | abc | 2022-09-21 | create    |
| 2  | xyz | 2022-09-21 | create    |
| 3  | moe | 2022-09-21 | create    |
+----+-----+------------+-----------+
```

where `id` is the primary key, how can I prevent the insertion of rows for
which the tuple of values of `uid`, `date` and `operation` already exists without
making all the columns part of the primary key?

**Background**

This is just to deal with a temporary situation.  I am rewriting an application and migrating data from SQLite to MariaDB.  I have a `cron` job which selects data some data from the SQLite DB and imports them to MariaDB.  With some tables I can rely on `INSERT IGNORE` to prevent duplicates being created if the primary key exists already, but not for all tables.

I could just import the once, write the application, and then just truncate and import again when I want to finalize them migration. However, it would be nice if I had current and consistent data to use during development.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! What's the matter with a `UNIQUE` index for those non-PK fields?

Comment: I hadn't thought of that, but there are actually futher columns for which I can't use ```UNIQUE```.  I'll update the question.

Comment: Can you make a subset `UNIQUE`?

Comment: Only the columns set which must be unique should be used in UNIQUE index. *but not for all tables* Why?

Comment: Your INSERT which imports shouldn't forbid the duplicated row insertion - this will break the whole insert. If you need to prevent the insertion for only some rows then you MUST use either INSERT IGNORE or INSERT ODKU or REPLACE - but all these statements needs in according UNIQUE index.

Comment: You may use another option for to renew the data - import into temporary table then add only non-existent rows with second query which checks for the row presence.

Comment: @loris I think Verace means, a composite unique index, so one index for all of the non-PK fields, e.g. defined on `(uid, date, operation)`. It doesn't matter that individually some of those fields aren't unique, the combination of all of them are, and that's your goal is to prevent duplicate tuples of those fields from being inserted.

Comment: I wanted to avoid using ```UNIQUE``` as the rows are not in general unique. They just happen to be in this temporary development situation. However, I solved the problem by just having the ```cron``` job insert an appropriate ```DELETE FROM``` at the beginning of the imported SQL.

Comment: Are you saying that it is possible to have two rows with exactly "abc | 2022-09-21 | create"?  AND meanwhile, you are trying to avoid such??

Comment: @RickJames: I know it is somewhat goofy, but yes.  I am trying to avoid the duplicate rows only when migrating the data. In the production setting such duplicate lines will be possible (although not that likely).  However, as I mentioned, just deleting the existing rows before inserting the data from the old DB achieves what I want.

Comment: Still not clear what _all_ the goals are.  (Ignoring the auto_inc id...)  Are there no _existing_ dup rows?  Do not add _add_ dup rows?  Remove any rows that are not in the new data?

Comment: I am moving from a situation where the the table ```users``` has a column ```uid```, which is the primary key, and a column ```create_date```.  Thus, currently there are no duplicate rows.  In the new schema, the ```user``` table no longer has a column ```create_date```.  Instead there is an additional table, ```user_events```, which has the structure shown in my question.  This allows a user to be create, deleted, and then recreated, such that all the dates of the events can be kept.  Currently, the field ```create_date``` will just be overwritten.